# How to hide Edit button based on state in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, formview

[image]

how can I hide the edit button when the state is "In Progress"
I tried doing ir.rule like [this](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-hide-the-edit-and-create-buttons-conditionally-131216) but it didn't work it only filter(domain) my treeview
I also tried to doing it in JavaScript but i can't find any odoo 11 sample

Comment: There is no good solution for standard Odoo. You could use ir.rule and just "remove" write/update rights. Problem with that solution: the user can click the Edit Button and change things, but with a write operation (for example clicking the Save button) the user will get a access error. As i said not a very good solution.

Comment: You can’t hide write button but you can definitely make fields read only based on this condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by inserting conditional CSS.

Frist add a html field with sanitize option set to False:

```
x_css = fields.Html(
    string='CSS',
    sanitize=False,
    compute='_compute_css',
    store=False,
)
```

Then add a compute method with your own dependances and conditions:

```
# Modify the "depends"
@api.depends('state_str_modify_me')
def _compute_css(self):
    for application in self:
        # Modify below condition
        if application.state_str_modify_me= 'In Progress':
            application.x_css = '<style>.o_form_button_edit {display: none !important;}</style>'
        else:
            application.x_css = False
```

Finally add it to the view:

```
<field name="x_css" invisible="1"/>
```